# React Admin - Make input for filter based on other resource

Tags: react-admin

I am using React Admin to make a dashboard and I have this Lead resource with the status field, that is computed based on another resource, Call, and wanted to make a filter component for Lead's list. The way it works is that for each lead, I query the last call (sorted by a date field) associated with this lead and get its status. The lead status is the status for the last call.

```
{ filter: { lead }, sort: { date: -1 }, limit: 1 }
```

*the lead status query*

I use this query to make a field (that appear in the list in the row of a single lead), and wanted to know how I can make an input component to use as a filter in the list. I know this pattern is weird, but  it's hard to change it in the backend because of how it's structured. I am open to suggestions concerning how to change this messy computed field situation, but as I said, I would be satisfied with knowing how I can create the input component.

Comment: You could achieve this using `FormDataConsumer `, so you can link 2 inputs, the second one depends of the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I'm going with is a computed field. In my case, as I use MongoDB, it will be done through an aggregation pipeline. As I'm using REST instead of GraphQL, I cannot use a resolver that would only be called in the need of the status field, sometimes resulting in an uneeded aggregation (getting the last Call for a given Lead). However, it won't incur in an additional roundtrip - and instead only consume more processing time in the DB - which would be necessary for react-admin to compute this field in through a reference. And status is an important field that will usually be needed anyways.